# cant map array of object query from mangodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please i am facing map is not a function error when i tried to map array of object from mongodb.

and the console.log returns the correct data but in string format. please help me on how to go about it. thanks

```
const [printz, setPrintz] = useState([ ])

    const getOrder = async() =>{
        try {
            const res = await axios.get("/products/receipt/all")
            setPrintz(res.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
     }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        getOrder()
    }, [ getOrder])

    console.log({DbDatas: printz}) // return the correct data


   {printz && printz.map(x =>(                   
        <tbody >
            <tr>
                <td>{x.product}</td>
                <td>{x.price}</td>
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
    )) }   
    </table>
```

bellow is the screenshot from the mongodb

[image: mongodb data]

...[image: console.log]

i think the problem is from the backend

```
router.get('/receipt/all', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const getprint = await Prints.find()
        res.status(200).json( getprint +'Succes!')
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(`Error fetching data!!! ${error}`)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's in string format. You should parse it by using `JSON.parse()`.
In this example

```
JSON.parse(printz).map()
```

Comment: thanks Abellay, i got another error now ... Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.